# Large Array to Map

Tags: scala, graph

I have a large text file that has 2 numbers on each row, meant to represent a directed edge between the first and second elements in the row. I am trying to construct a graph in scala, by representing this as a `Map[tailOfEdge,ArrayofHeadsOfEdges]`

Such that if my file has

```
   1   2
   1   3
   2   3
```

THis should be `Map(1-> Array(2,3),2-> Array(3))`

However, my file is very large (~5 million rows)

I initially tried to read the entirety of the file, use `toArray` and then use `groupBy` and accumulate that way. However, I keep running into a heap size issue (not to mention that his is probably a very naive way of doing this)

For now, what is working for me (although incredibly slow) is creating a mutable map, looping through each line of the file (with a for loop), split the line into the 2 numbers. All edges for a given node are contigious in the file, so I just keep track of what node I'm expecting, if it is the same node, I accumulate the new edge, if it is a new node then I add the completed accumulated array to the map, reset the node I'm expecting and restart the accumulation array with this new list.

There is surely a better way of doing this....

Comment: What you are doing sounds pretty close to optimal from a performance point of view. It should not be slow. Can you post the code?

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn thanks for the response. I will go with the foldLeft code posted below. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this pretty cleanly with a left fold and an immutable map:

```
val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(args(0))

val graph = source.getLines.foldLeft[Map[Int, Vector[Int]]](
  Map.empty withDefaultValue Vector.empty
) {
  case (acc, line) => line.trim.split("\\s+").map(_.toInt) match {
    case Array(k, v) => acc.updated(k, acc(k) :+ v)
  }
}

source.close()
```

This runs on a file with five million rows in about seven seconds on my machine. `getLines` is an iterator, so you don't need to read the entire file into memory.

I'm not sure what "incredibly slow" means for you. This implementation doesn't make any assumptions about the order of keys in the file, and if you really need it to be faster than a million-ish rows a second, you should be able to take advantage of the fact that they're ordered. But it probably won't help all that much, and will almost certainly involve more complex code.

You could also use arrays instead of vectors—I've just gone with vectors here to show that you don't even need the lists of heads to be mutable.

Comment: mmm. I am not getting that kind of performance. I wonder if it is my machine. I will try again later on a different computer....

Comment: For reference, I'm on an aging ThinkPad running Arch Linux and OpenJDK's JDK 7. The example file was five million pairs of random numbers between zero and a hundred.

Comment: I'm actually getting some strange behavior, but might be the file.

     `scala> val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("./SCC.txt")`
     source: scala.io.BufferedSource = non-empty iterator

     `scala> source.getLines.take(2).toList`
     `res9: List[String] = List("94 ", "72 28395 ")`

and then
      `scala> val l=for(line<-source.getLines) yield line.split("\\s+").length`
`l: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator`

`scala> l.filter(_!=2).toList`
`res14: List[Int] = List(1)`

But there shouldn't be any such numbers..

Comment: realized i never accepted this, despite having used it. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

If your input sequence is really big, the other solution will OOME eventually.  Here's my imperative solution, which relies on the caller to cleanly dispose of groups as they're produced, but AFAICT runs in constant stack and retains minimal heap for its own use. :)

Hopefully someone else can come up with a fold over a Stream or somesuch that will have similar performance characteristics as long as you're careful not to retain references to the head.

```
/**
 * @param in       the input
 * @param disposal a function that will dispose of groups as they're identified
 */
def groupByInfinite[A,B](in: Iterator[(A,B)])(disposal: (A,Seq[B]) => Unit) {

  /**
   * @param in      the input
   * @param current the current A value
   * @param got     the B values being accumulated for the current A value
   */
  @tailrec
  def group0(in: Iterator[(A,B)], current: A, got: Seq[B]) {
    if (in.hasNext) {
      val (a,b) = in.next()
      if (a == current) {
        group0(in, a, got :+ b)
      } else {
        disposal(current, got)
        group0(in, a, Vector(b))
      }
    } else {
      disposal(current, got)
    }
  }

  if (in.hasNext) {
    val (a,b) = in.next()
    group0(in, a, Vector(b))
  }
}
```

Comment: If the goal is to build a map, I don't see how the memory usage here would be dramatically different from the left fold solution.

Comment: Yep, you're right, but sometimes it's more important to be able to process the data at all rather than to fit it into some contiguous data structure. :)